# How to access chrome's devtools -> Sources -> Page section contents from a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension that needs to access the `devtools/inspect -> Sources -> Pages` content. Unable to find a API(unable to determine the correct one)- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/

I need to traverse the whole content present under `Pages` to find a specific directory and file name.

I'm new to developing Chrome extension. My gratitude in advance for your assistance!